# PyYAML list order

Tags: python

I have a yaml file that contains the following:

```
Filer_Po:
    - description <dsc_here>
    - switchport
    - switchport mode private-vlan trunk promiscuous
    - spanning-tree port type edge trunk
    - spanning-tree bpduguard enable
    - speed 10000
    - flowcontrol receive on
    - flowcontrol send on
    - mtu 9216
    - storm-control broadcast level 20.00
    - switchport private-vlan trunk native vlan 1093
    - switchport private-vlan trunk allowed vlan 1094,1099
    - switchport private-vlan mapping trunk 1093 1094
    - no lacp graceful-convergence
    - no shutdown
```

I load the file using the following code:

```
with open(int_cmd_file, 'r') as stream:
    try:
        int_cmd_dic = yaml.load(stream)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Using the command `print json.dumps(int_cmd_dic, indent=4)` I get the following output.

```
{
    "Filer_Po": [
        "description <dsc_here>",
        "switchport",
        "switchport mode private-vlan trunk promiscuous",
        "speed 10000",
        "no lacp graceful-convergence",
        "spanning-tree port type edge trunk",
        "spanning-tree bpduguard enable",
        "flowcontrol receive on",
        "flowcontrol send on",
        "mtu 9216",
        "storm-control broadcast level 20.00",
        "switchport private-vlan trunk native vlan 1093",
        "switchport private-vlan trunk allowed vlan 1094,1099",
        "switchport private-vlan mapping trunk 1093 1094",
        "no shutdown"
    ]
}
```

Note that 'speed 10000' is one element earlier in the list than it was defined in the Yaml file.  How do I maintain the order of the list as defined?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in either Python 2 or Python 3.  I note that your input & output lists differ in more ways than just the location of `speed 10000`; are you sure you're reading what you think you're reading?

Comment: I found the problem.  It was a DP error (dumb programmer).  I misread one of the variables in the file path, thus I was making changes to the wrong file.